# ¿Cómo obtener XSRF-TOKEN con HTTParty para realizar peticiones POST?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cabeceras-http

Intento hacer scrapping a una pagina utilizando **RUBY** y quiero enviar un post que incluye **X-XSRF-TOKEN** pero no sé cómo obtener el valor.

Cuando hago un **GET** a la pagina inicial e inspecciono me muestra un cookie llamado **XSFR-TOKEN** pero cuando intento obtenerlo mediante HTTParty para armar la solicitud **POST** no me aparece en el encabezado.

```
response = HTTParty.get('https://www.dominio.com/')
puts response.headers
```

La verdad no se como obtener el valor X-XSRF-TOKEN para poder enviar POST sin que el servidor rechace las peticiones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el contenido de tu página probablemente tu página tenga un tag

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="prok/b/nmPmxJkucfPah8YGGhRM9f2Pyy2vL+pJ/4w8R8EW2kVX/bLX4XwlytqaCjZ==" />
```

Deberías capturar el `content` para luego agregarlo como una cookie `X-CSRF-Token` en tu request.
Podrías usar [nokogiri](https://nokogiri.org/) para parsear el DOM o buscar el contenido en tu `response.body`.